# In a multi-repo deploy, how can I can I keep the pipelines co-located with their source code

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

I have a `Deploy to IBM Cloud` button that deploys 3 git repos and works great except I have a maintenance problem.  If I make an edit in one of the repos which impacts how it is built, I have to change the `pipeline.yml` which exists in another repo, namely in the same repo as my `.bluemix\toolchain.yml`.  I would prefer to have my `pipeline.yml` files self-contained in the repo they actually pertain to.  My `toolchain.yml` has 3 entries like:

`services:
  dashboard-build:
    service_id: pipeline
    parameters:
      services:
        - dashboard-repo
      name: 'dashboard-{{toolchain.name}}'
      configuration:
        content:
          $ref: dashboard.pipeline.yml
          $refType: text`

I tried an absolute path like:
`ref: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/org/repo/master/.bluemix/dashboard.pipeline.yml` but it errored out with

> repository contains an invalid template. File not found

Can I change the pipeline's location to be in its own repository or does it have to be co-located with the `toolchain.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you've guessed any files referenced with `$ref` or `$text` must be co-located in either the same repo or zip file. We might offer support for referencing and extending another template in the future but there is nothing concrete there yet.

--

Also...
`$text` should be used in preference to `$ref` and `$refType` here.

The pipeline's "content" element expects raw text and historically that is why we added `$refType: text`. However, `$ref` as specified in JSON Reference explicitly ignores siblings so although we have support for `$refType` currently it would be better to just use `$text` going forward.

`content:
  $text: dashboard.pipeline.yml`

Comment: Thanks @simon-kaegi , I will change them to `$text`.  But to be clear, do I have to use that method to reference them, or is there an alternative way where I could make the location absolute?

Comment: Sorry just saw this -- all locations must be relative